# PIG: CONCAT A relation OUTPUT to another RELATION

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, epoch

Sorry for the wrong phrasing of question.
I am new to stackoverflow as well as I am completely new to PIG and trying to experiment on my own.

I have a scenario where to process the words.t file and data.txt file.

words.txt

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

data.txt

```
{"created_at":"18:47:31,Sun Sep 30 2012","text":"RT @Joey7Barton: ..give a word1 about whether the americans wins a Ryder cup. I mean surely he has slightly more important matters. #fami ...","user_id":450990391,"id":252479809098223616}
```

I need to get the output as

**(word1_epochtime){complete data which matched in text attribute}**

i.e

```
(word1_1234567890){"created_at":"18:47:31,Sun Sep 30 2012","text":"RT @Joey7Barton: ..give a word1 about whether the americans wins a Ryder cup. I mean surely he has slightly more important matters. #fami ...","user_id":450990391,"id":252479809098223616}
```

I have got the ouput as

> (word1){"created_at":"18:47:31,Sun Sep 30 2012","text":"RT @Joey7Barton: ..give a
>   word1 about whether the americans wins a Ryder cup. I mean surely he
>   has slightly more important matters. #fami
>   ...","user_id":450990391,"id":252479809098223616}

by using this script.

```
load words.txt
load data.txt
c = cross words,data;
d = FILTER c BY (data::text MATCHES CONCAT(CONCAT('.*',words::word),'.*'));
e =  foreach (group d BY word) {data);
```

and I got the epochtime with the words as

```
time = FOREACH words GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(word,'_'),(chararray)ToUnixTime(CurrentTime(created_at));
```

But I am unable to CONCAT the words with time.

How can i get the output as

```
(word1_time){data}
```

Please feel free to suggest me for the above.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think i got the output.
here is the script that I have written.

```
d = FILTER c BY (data::text MATCHES CONCAT(CONCAT('.*',word::word),'.*'));
e = FOREACH d GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(word,'_'),(chararray)ToUnixTime(CurrentTime(created_at))) as epochtime;
f = foreach (group e BY epochtime) {data}
dump f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [this reference](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#concat), CONCAT takes in two "Fields" as an input. I think in your case the problem is `(chararray)ToUnixTime(CurrentTime())`, is not being a field name. You could generate field that represents the current timestamp value and use it then in your concat function.

Comment: thanks for your replay Amit. Actually its my mistake that i didn't mentioned it properly.I am getting the epoch time based on created_at attribute.I have edited the question.can you please recheck once.Please suggest me.